# Live stream Elevenlabs audio on Safari using a Flask built API

Tags: python, flask, ffmpeg, safari, audio-streaming

I am attempting to return an audio stream to my website via my flask api. The api call will generate some content and then call Elevenlabs API to produce the audio. I then want this audio sent back to my website as a stream. The code I initially created works great on Chrome, but on desktop Safari and iOS it will not work. I get no response header from the api call.

Here it the initial code:

```
@application.route('/get-audio', methods=['GET'])
def get_audio():
    # Get data from request (you might be getting a text or some parameters based on which audio is generated)
    data = request.args.get('data')

    def generate():
        url = "https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/EXAVITQu4vr4xnSDxMaL/stream"
    
        headers = {
            "Accept": "audio/mpeg",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "xi-api-key": "api_key"
        }
    
        data = {
            "text": data,
            "model_id": "eleven_monolingual_v1",
            "voice_settings": {
                "stability": 0.5,
                "similarity_boost": 0.5
            }
        }
    
        try:
            response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers, stream=True)
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                yield chunk
        except requests.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error fetching audio: {e}")

    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()), content_type='audio/mpeg')
```

I then attempted to use ffmpeg to return the audio stream, but still with no luck. The best I could do was save the file and then get safari to read from that file.

```
@application.route('/get-audio', methods=['GET'])
def get_audio():    
    audio_generator = generate_track(data)
    return Response(audio_generator, content_type="audio/aac")
   
def generate_track(data)
[........]
    try:
        response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers, stream=True)

        ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(
            ["ffmpeg", "-i", "pipe:0", "-f", "adts", "-"],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            bufsize=10**8 
        )

        for audio_chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
            aac_audio, _ = ffmpeg_process.communicate(input=audio_chunk)
            yield aac_audio

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching audios: {e}")
```

I've come across a few potential solutions but never managed to adapt one to my code, with the particularity here being trying to stream an incoming stream via my api.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This work for me using elevenlabs 0.22

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from elevenlabs import generate, set_api_key, stream
import key
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

set_api_key(key.ELEVENLABS_API_KEY)

def generate_text():
    yield "Hi there, I'm Eleven "
    yield "I'm a text to speech API "

@app.route("/speak", methods=["POST"])
def speak():
    audio = generate(
        text=generate_text(),
        voice="Antoni",
        model="eleven_multilingual_v2",
        stream=True
    )
    stream(audio)
```

Comment: Hi, while answering it's better to add some details, or citations,  explaining why this can work well. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you